# Test suite failed to run. Cannot find module '@testing-library/jest-native' running a test using react native testing library

Tags: javascript, react-native, jestjs, babeljs, react-native-testing-library

I am running a test for a component that needs to check if it has a particular CSS style. As the React Native Testing Library doesn't have this function by default, I installed the @testing-library/react-native to use toHaveStyle from there but while running a test I get an error: Test suite failed to run. Cannot find module '@testing-library/jest-native' from "a path to my test file here". Here is my test and the jest config:

```js
// test file
import React from 'react';
import {toHaveStyle} from '@testing-library/jest-native';

describe('JobForm', () => {
  expect.extend({toHaveStyle});
  // ....
});


// package.json
{
//...
   "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ],
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "node_modules/(?!(jest-)?@?react-native|@react-native-community|@react-navigation|aws-amplify-react-native|@ui-kitten)"
        ],
        "setupFiles": [
            "<rootDir>/jest.setup.js",
            "./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/jestSetup.js"
        ]
    }
}

//jest.setup.js
import mockRNCNetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo/jest/netinfo-mock.js';
import mockAsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage/jest/async-storage-mock';

jest.mock('@react-native-community/netinfo', () => mockRNCNetInfo);
jest.mock('@react-native-async-storage/async-storage', () => mockAsyncStorage);
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot to finish the configuration from the [Usage section](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native#usage) (a section below the [Installation section](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-native#installation)) from the `@testing-library/jest-native` package. All you need to do is add this line to your setup file:

```js
import '@testing-library/jest-native/extend-expect';
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your answer. The section you sent me a link to also mentiones the second approach: Alternatively, you can selectively import only the matchers you intend to use, and extend jest's expect yourself:

import { toBeEmptyElement, toHaveTextContent } from '@testing-library/jest-native';

expect.extend({ toBeEmptyElement, toHaveTextContent });
And this one I did use and I am still getting the error

Comment: I also tried importing this statement to the test file and I am still getting an error =/

Comment: Also, I am not sure which setup file?

Comment: Your setup file is the one described inside your `package.json` file, at `jest.setupFiles`. From what I saw, it is the `jest.setup.js` file. Just try adding the line I mentioned and check if works. If it doesn't, could you please provide a message of error (editing your answer maybe)?

Comment: Also, ideally, you should keep those things (even importing just the used matchers) inside the setup file and import them from there. I also think it worth asking but: have you run `npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-native`?

Comment: If I add this import statement to the jest.setup.js and run npm test, all of my tests fail (ReferenceError: expect is not defined). And yes, I did run npm install --save-dev @testing-library/jest-native

Comment: Remember to use **just one of the options**: the `import` or the `extend` option. If you use the second one, remember to follow the informed import from the INFO box at [`jest` doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect) (and you can see [mentioned here at the TypeScript tab](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#expectextendmatchers)): `import { expect } from '@jest/globals';`

Answer (score 0):

In case of config or import issues it's always a good idea to compare you config against model one provided by RNTL team. RNTL has a [basic example app](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/tree/main/examples/basic) that is useful for that purpose, especially that it also includes `@testing-library/jest-native`.